# Embedded git repository that tracks our changes?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Similar to git's submodule functionality, I'd like to embed a clone of a remote repository in my own. However, I would like the ability to make changes to our embedded version while still maintaining the ability to pull updates from the remote as well. I don't see how I can do this with a submodule. Is this functionally possible? Right now I just have the remote source directory copied into my repository and while that allows me to track my local changes, it loses the ability to pull updates from the remote repository or manage branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your situation you may want subtrees: http://help.github.com/subtree-merge/. You can pull and update the subtree in a Makefile or cron if you need to be up to date.

Comment: From my testing it looks like this replicates the behavior we want. As long as we can do occasional pulls we should be fine. Daily updates aren't necessary. I'll still have to still how it handles, but it looks good.

Comment: Link above not valid anymore - think you want to update it to http://help.github.com/subtree-merge/

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used braid to manage this: https://github.com/evilchelu/braid/wiki/

Comment: Looks interesting but I can't see a way to checkout branches using braid. Normally after cloning the remote I would git checkout branch, but I don't see a way to do that with braid. I am a relative git newbie though.

Comment: You would make a branch on YOUR repo, as the vendor code is now tracked there. Braid handles merging in the upstream changes into your customized tree. (Or possibly the other way around.)